# Match exact word in bash script, extract number from string

Tags: bash, shell, text-parsing

I'm trying to create a very simple bash script that will open new link base on the input command

**Use case #1**

```
$ ./myscript longname55445
```

It should take the number **55445** and then assign that to a variable which will later be use to open new link based on the given number.

**Use case #2**

```
$ ./myscript l55445
```

It should do the exact same thing as above by taking the number and then open the same link.

**Use case #3**

```
$ ./myscript 55445
```

If no prefix given then we just simply open that same link as a fallback.

So far this is what I have

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE_URL=http://api.domain.com
input=$1
command=${input:0:1}

if [ "$command" == "longname" ]; then
  number=${input:1:${#input}}
  url="$BASE_URL?id="$number
  open $url
elseif [ "$command" == "l" ]; then
   number=${input:1:${#input}}
  url="$BASE_URL?id="$number
  open $url
else
  number=${input:1:${#input}}
  url="$BASE_URL?id="$number
  open $url
fi
```

But this will always fallback to the `elseif` there.

I'm using `zsh` at the moment.

Comment: The title mentions `bash`, and your script uses `sh` (which _happens_ to  essentially be `bash` on your platform, which I presume to be OSX, due to use of `open` for opening a URL). Since you're using `bash`-specific features, it's better to use a `bash` shebang. It's also not clear how `zsh` factors into this - perhaps just remove its mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see whether this construct is helpful for your purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="longname55445"
echo "${name##*[A-Za-z]}"
```

this assumes a letter adjacent to number.

The following is **NOT**  another way to write the same, because it is wrong.
Please see comments below by mklement0, who noticed this. Mea culpa.

```
echo "${name##*[:letter:]}"
```

Comment: this will take `foobar55445` and return 55445, may not be expected.

Comment: actually that is how i understood that it should work, strip leading chars (letters), whether those are "longname" or "foo"

Comment: @Bushmills that other guy's suggestion is good. if you read OP's code, you will see, he only wants to extract number if input was leading with `l or longname`

Comment: should have asked clarification, before trying to interpret original poster's true intentions incorrectly.

Comment: But we were discussing whether that's what you actually wanted - as it deviates from the problem description when taking it literally. Be aware that it may have the aforementioned "side effects"

Comment: @Bushmills yes, I'm only looking for the numbers that is given in the input.

Comment: so It was a lucky guess.  Still, test some cases, as the result may be surprising.  For example. with   foo1234x  - this take everything away from string, from first char until last letter.  if a letter is behind number, number is taken away too.  You could alternatively explore  echo "${name##*[!0-9]}"  which takes everything away up and until a number at the end, which may work better with input like  "foo:1234"

Comment: `[:letter:]` doesn't work the way you intended: due to lack of surrounding `[..]`, it's not a named character class, but a _set of individual characters_ (`:`, `l`, ...). It just happens to work in this particular case, because `e` is among the characters and the input string happens to end in `e`. Aside from that, the name of the class you're looking for is `alpha`, not `letter`. Therefore: What you wanted is `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: To summarize: Your solution works fine, as long as the last letter (or non-digit, in your alternate solution with `*[!0-9]`) in the input string comes BEFORE the number - which may suffice to solve the OP's problem. Generally, limitations in `bash`'s pattern matching prevent a true strip-an-all-letters-prefix solution. Short of looping over each character, there is no pure bash solution I'm aware of.

Comment: An approximation of that could be  "${name#${name%%[0-9]*}}"  which strips leading string up to and exclusive of the first numeral. This deals better with the case of a trailing non-digit. Nice spotting of nonexisting character class!

Comment: Indeed that's better - clever nesting of parameter expansion: that _does_ strip an all-nondigits prefix. (As an aside: if you want me to be notified of a response, you'll have to include '@mklement0' in it.)

Answer (score 3):

```
input=$1
command=${input:0:1}
```

sets `command` to the first character of the first argument. It's not possible for a one character string to be equal to an eight-character string ("longname"), so the `if` condition must always fail.

Furthermore, both your `elseif` and your `else` clauses set

```
number=${input:1:${#input}}
```

Which you could have written more simply as

```
number=${input:1}
```

But in both cases, you're dropping the first character of `input`. Presumably in the `else` case, you wanted the entire first argument.

Comment: +1 for a helpful explanation of the problem with the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You have `command=${input:0:1}`

It takes the **first single** char, and you compare it to `"longname"`, of course it will fail, and go to elseif.

The key problem is to check if the input is beginning with `l` or `longname`or `nothing`. If in one of the 3 cases, take the trailing numbers.

One grep line could do it, you can just grep on `input` and get the returned text:

```
kent$  grep -Po '(?<=longname|l|^)\d+' <<<"l234"
234

kent$  grep -Po '(?<=longname|l|^)\d+' <<<"longname234"
234

kent$  grep -Po '(?<=longname|l|^)\d+' <<<"234"        
234

kent$  grep -Po '(?<=longname|l|^)\d+' <<<"foobar234"
<we got nothing>
```

Comment: By relying on `grep -P`, your solution becomes platform-dependent (requires GNU `grep`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex matching in `bash`.

```
[[ $1 =~ [0-9]+ ]] && number=$BASH_REMATCH
```

You can also use regex matching in `zsh`.

```
[[ $1 =~ [0-9]+ ]] && number=$MATCH
```

Comment: +1 for a pure bash (zsh) approach to extracting a number from a string. However, you don't need a capture group: `[[ $1 =~ [0-9]+ ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH}` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's following clarification in a comment,

> I'm only looking for the numbers [...] given in the input.

the solution can be simplified as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_URL='http://api.domain.com'

  # Strip all non-digits from the 1st argument to get the desired number.
number=$(tr -dC '[:digit:]' <<<"$1")

open "$BASE_URL?id=$number"
```

Note the use of a **`bash`** shebang, given the use of 'bashism' `<<<` (which could easily be restated in a POSIX-compliant manner).

Similarly, the OP's original code should use a `bash` shebang, too, due to use of non-POSIX substring extraction syntax.

However, judging by the use of `open` to open a URL, the OP appears to be on OSX, where `sh` is essentially `bash` (though invocation as `sh` *does* change behavior), so it'll still work *there*. Generally, though, it's safer to be explicit about the required shell.